# React.js "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, frontend, state

So I'm working on learning full stack using React.js with a friend. He's been helping me a ton but unfortunately, isn't available for the next few days so I thought I'd ask here. I know this issue has to deal with the way my `useState([])` is set up or something along those lines. Any advice would be great.

````
import "./App.css";
import AddTodoButton from "./components/AddTodoButton/AddTodoButton";
import { Draggable, Droppable } from 'react-drag-and-drop';
import Todo from "./components/Todo/Todo";

function App() {
  const [todoTodos, setTodoTodos] = useState([]);
  const [inProgressTodos, setInProgressTodos] = useState([]);
  const [doneTodos, setDoneTodos] = useState([]);
  const handleAddTodo = (newTodoToAdd) => {
    setTodoTodos([...todoTodos, newTodoToAdd]);
  };

  const setStateInProgress = (todo) => {
    setInProgressTodos([...inProgressTodos, todo]);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="swimlane-container">
        <Droppable><Swimlane title="Todo" todos={todoTodos} /></Droppable>
        <Droppable types={['todo']} onDrop={setStateInProgress()}><Swimlane title="In progress" todos={inProgressTodos} /></Droppable>
        <Droppable><Swimlane title="Done" todos={doneTodos} /></Droppable>
      </div>
      <div>
        <AddTodoButton onAddTodo={handleAddTodo} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
  
}

export default App;```
````

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of calling `setStateInProgress()` on `onDrop` event. Instead you should just send the function reference.

Because when you do `setStateInProgress()` this function gets called during render, and in this function state is getting updated which will trigger a re-render. So this will be a cycle and hence the error.

Make the changes like below

```js
<Droppable types={['todo']} onDrop={setStateInProgress}><Swimlane title="In progress" todos={inProgressTodos} /></Droppable>
```

Hope this helps.